# ERROR: JUnitTask doesn't support nested text data (;)

Tags: ant, junit4

I've written following junit target in build.xml,

```
<target name="test-1" depends="compile">
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>          
    <test name="com.sample.CalcTest"
             haltonfailure="no" outfile="result" todir="${test.report.dir}">
      <formatter type="plain"/>;
      <formatter type="xml"/>
    </test>
  </junit>
</target>
```

build-path has all the jars including junit jar.
When I execute this target, it throws following error. Can some one suggest what am I missing here?

Junit version : 4.10
ERROR:

```
class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask doesn't support nested text data (;).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unnecessary `;` after `<formatter type="plain"/>`, remove it.